# Django enum named groups

Tags: django, enums

I want a listing to be able to have a specific category, so the seller will choose a general category and then onto a more specific one, for example:

Men's Wear:

- Jeans:

  - Skinny Fit
  - Slim Fit
  - Regular Fit
- Pants:

  - Slim Fit
  - Formal
  - Casual

Women's Apparel:

- Tops:

  - Tunics
- Denim:

  - Jeans

I tried the named groups like in django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices-named-groups

> MEDIA_CHOICES = [
> ('Audio', (
> ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
> ('cd', 'CD'),
> )
> ),
> ('Video', (
> ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
> ('dvd', 'DVD'),
> )
> ),
> ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
> ]

But when I tried, it gives the error

```
product.Listing.category: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
```

here is my code:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
CATEGORY = [
  ('Women\'s Apparel', (
          ('Dresses', (
                  ('party_dresses', 'Party Dresses'),
              )
          ),
      ),
  ),
]

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
new_condition = models.BooleanField()
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=255)
```

why is it showing error ? is it because the enum groups cant be nested more than 1 level ?
thank you

Comment: As far as I know, you can only do this "two levels" deep, so no three.

Comment: You will have to do proper data modeling instead, also I would not place this in enum as store article categories certainly can change